# How can I create a list of letters/numbers with a specific repeating pattern?

Tags: r, combn

Basically I have 25 96-well plates and I need to create a list of every possible well where P = plate, the next number is the plate number (1-25), the next letter corresponds to the row on the plate (A-H), and the last number corresponds to the column on the plate (1-12). I need to have a unique code (for example P5H6) for each well.

What code can I input into R so that I get a list of 2400 unique codes corresponding to each well?

I have tried using the paste code but I don't know how to get each variable to change accordingly.

```
paste("P1", LETTERS[1], 1:12, sep="")
```

Comment: You could do `do.call("paste0", c(expand.grid("P", 1:25, LETTERS[1:8], 1:12)))`

Comment: or using `tidyr` it would be ```crossing("P", 1:25, LETTERS[1:8], 1:12) %>% unite(. , "id", 1:ncol(.), sep = "") %>% .[["id"]]```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is certainly not the most efficient solution but this did work for me and uses the most basic of commands. I am interested in learning more elegant solutions that are available but I hope this helps some!

```
wells <- c()
p <- 25
r <- 8
c <- 12
i <- j <- k <- 1
for (i in 1:p){
  repeat{
    for (j in 1:r){
      repeat{
        for (k in 1:c){
          repeat{
            wells <- as.list(c(wells, paste("P", i, LETTERS[j], k, sep = "")))
            break
          }
          k <- k + 1
        }
        break
      }
      j <- j + 1
    }
    break
  }
  i <- i + 1
}
```